# How to control multiple vehicles simultaneously in SUMO?

Tags: python, sumo

I'm trying to control all vehicles in SUMO by changing their speed. I code in Python and use a for loop like

```
for ID in traci.vehicle.getIDList():
    traci.vehicle.setSpeed(ID, speed[ID])
```

where speed is a predefined list because each vehicle has a different speed. However, this way takes a lot of time when there are too many vehicles. I wonder is there some other ways to control multiple vehicles simultaneously to reduce the time cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you execution speed is your major concern try using libsumo instead of traci. Most of the time it is a dropin replacement: `ìmport libsumo as traci`. If you only want to set a maximum speed you could consider using a variable speed sign but since you already seem to have vehicle specific speeds this is probably not a solution.